# How do I use ServiceStack.Text in my web api project

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core, servicestack-text

I am new to ServiceStack.Text and finding it hard how to use it in my project. I did a nuget install but how do I add it to my formatters collection so it uses that by default?

I am using Asp.Net Core windows project.

I don't know how to use this DLL I read that it needs some custom formatter so I added it using this:

```
services.AddMvc().AddMvcOptions(options => {

                options.InputFormatters.Clear();
                options.InputFormatters.Add(new ServiceStackTextFormatter());

            });
```

and this is the actual class:

```
 public class ServiceStackTextFormatter : MediaTypeFormatter
    {
        //Uses ISO8601 date by default
        private DateHandler _dateHandler = DateHandler.ISO8601;

        public ServiceStackTextFormatter(DateHandler dateHandler)
            : this()
        {
            _dateHandler = dateHandler;
        }

        public ServiceStackTextFormatter()
        {
            SupportedMediaTypes.Add(new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/json"));

            SupportedEncodings.Add(new UTF8Encoding(encoderShouldEmitUTF8Identifier: false, throwOnInvalidBytes: true));

            //TODO: Add XHR Header mapping. Will add this after a discussion with aspnetwebstack team: See: http://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/discussions/350758
        }

        public override Task<object> ReadFromStreamAsync(Type type, System.IO.Stream stream, HttpContent content, IFormatterLogger formatterLogger)
        {
            return Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
            {
                using (var scope = JsConfig.BeginScope())
                {
                    scope.DateHandler = _dateHandler;
                    JsConfig.DateHandler = _dateHandler;
                    var result = JsonSerializer.DeserializeFromStream(type, stream);
                    return result;
                }
            });
        }

        public override Task WriteToStreamAsync(Type type, object value, System.IO.Stream stream, HttpContent content, TransportContext transportContext)
        {
            return Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
            {
                using (var scope = JsConfig.BeginScope())
                {
                    scope.DateHandler = _dateHandler;
                    JsonSerializer.SerializeToStream(value, type, stream);
                }
            });
        }

        public override bool CanReadType(Type type)
        {
            if (type == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException("type");
            }

            return true;
        }

        public override bool CanWriteType(Type type)
        {
            if (type == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException("type");
            }

            return true;
        }
    }
```

But the project gives me error

```
cannot convert from 'Helpers.ServiceStackTextFormatter' to 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Formatters.IInputFormatter'
```

I am a bit frustrated as there is no getting started guide available anywhere. How would I tell the .Net to use this DLL by default?

Any help is appreciated.